# UITableView - Accessing in Code from ViewWillAppear

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I would like to manipulate table cells in my UITableView as it comes back from its detail view, to remind the user what row they last selected. The UITableView was created in IB and there currently isn't a @property or custom class for the UITableView or any other handle. Clearly, it exists when, the user is coming back from the detail view and viewWillAppear is called but I don't see any handle in the debugger for my UITableView.

Any way to simply get a handle to the IB tableView object?

```
// - The Containing ViewController
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {


      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

      NSIndexPath *selected = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

      if(selected){

        //Do something stylish with the last-selected row
        NSLog(@"Last row selected was: %@",selected);

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a class member of NSIndexPath * and set it inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Then, when viewWillAppear executes, when the user navigates back fram the table view detail, I have the last-selected row so I can easily highlight it or treat it any way I want:

```
 //The Containing View Controller
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     if(self.lastSelectedRow){

        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.lastSelectedRow animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];


      }  
}
```